# Excel VBA sum(sumifs) within sumproduct only works with F9

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Situation:

```
Row 1: Variable | Margin | Sales
Row 2: banana   | 2      | 10
Row 3: apple    | 5      | 20
Row 4: apple    | 10     | 20
```

"Variable" sits in column A, row 1.

Sales = name range for variable column i.e. A2:A4
Fruit = name range for "apple" and "banana" i.e. {apple;banana}

I have the above table and what to find the weighted average Margin. The weighting is based on sales.

Formula used: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4/(SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C4,sales,fruit))))`

Problem:

When I use this formula I get #DIV/0!
If i step into the formula and press F9 I get 6.40 which is the correct answer.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I get 6.40 without stepping into the formula with F9.

Note:

I would like to avoid using this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4/(SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C4,sales,{"apple","banana"}))))`
The range of fruit included in the calculation is dynamic. Sometimes I'd like to include only banana, sometimes only apple and I could make it dynamic by changing the cells within the fruit named range.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Your formula evaluates correctly as an *array* (CSE) formula; provided you entered correctly the named ranges.

Comment: Sorry, this is not VBA, just a formula within Excel

Comment: Your *Excel formula* worked for me (the first one) when entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. And I did not get `DIV!0` in any case. I entered the following names: `fruit:  ={"apple";"banana"}` and `sales: =Sheet3!$A$2:$A$4`.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H! Does that mean this formula is an array within an array, since sumproduct is an array?

Comment: I guess so, because the formula inside `SUM` is an array formula. However if you use `SUMPRODUCT` at *both places* it works pretty well as a normal formula.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H Yes! These two formula are the same result                                               ={SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4/(SUM(SUMIFS(C2:C4,sales,fruit))))} and =SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4/(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(sales,fruit,FALSE)),C2:C4))